# ASPNET 5 webapplication on Linux Database issue

Tags: .net, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, sqlite, asp.net-core-mvc

I originally built an aspnet 5 MVC6 application from the web app template of aspnet 5 on windows which for working fine(thw db was working fine). But when i run it on linux it creates a DB issue(`System.PlatformNotSupportedException: Integrated Security is not supported on non-Windows platform.`).

I surfed the net for a possible solution. Some suggest to use SQLlite. Not really sure what is the best option. Can I use the default DB support provided by microsoft (i.e. MSSQL) on linux? Other solutions are also welcome.

Comment: You can use Postgress (Npgsql provider)

Comment: Pretty soon RC 2 and RC 3 will be released and Microsoft has solved NTLM and Kerberos issues on non Windows platforms. You just hit a temporary limitation of an old build.

Comment: @ErikEJ can i make use of the scaffolding advantages even if I use postgress?

Comment: Yes... https://github.com/npgsql/npgsql/issues/965